# Assign function to variable and get variable name from inside said function

Tags: python

```
def my_function():
   ... 

my_variable = my_function
my_variable()
```

In this case, is there a way to get `my_variable` as string from inside `my_function`?

Comment: this code doesn't make sense. Can you explain in broader terms what you are trying to do?

Comment: I want to get the effective name of the function when it's being called.

Comment: That is not something you'd ordinarily want to do. Variable *names* are not data and should not influence a program's behaviour.

Comment: I'm not asking for permission or if it's right to do so, I'm asking whether it's possible.

Answer (score 1):

You could look into `globals()` for instances of the function.

```
def my_func():
    names = [k for k,v in globals().items() if str(v).startswith("<function my_func ")]
    print(names[1:]) #names[0] is "my_func"

my_var = my_func
my_var() #['my_var']

asd = my_func
asd() #['my_var', 'asd']
```